# Injecting an environment variable from gulp to webpack

Tags: node.js, gulp, webpack

I have a gulpfile from which I'm initiating webpack bundling. The webpack configuration has an alias defined that uses `process.env.NODE_ENV` as shown below

```
.
.
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", "js", "jsx"],
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"],
    alias: {
        config: path.join(__dirname, ('config.' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js'))
    }
}..
```

In the gulpfile, I have 2 tasks that execute in sequence

1. `set-env` that sets the environment variable using `gulp-env` as follows

   ```
   gulpEnv({
       vars: {
           NODE_ENV: 'dev'
       }
   });
   ```
2. `webpack` task that depends on the previous task and executes only when the first is completed

Here the variable is not getting injected properly it seems. The file name is getting resolved as `config.undefined.js`. Is there something wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my approach it to something like this

**Webpack**

```
var NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

var config = {
    .
    .
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", "js", "jsx"],
        extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"],
        alias: {
            //<envt> will be injected by gulp
            config: config: path.join(__dirname, ('config.<envt>.js'))
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

//If webpack is directly invoked with NODE_ENV, replacement will happen here
if (NODE_ENV) {
    config['resolve']['alias']['config'] = config['resolve']['alias']['config'].replace(/<envt>/, NODE_ENV);
}

module.exports = config;
```

**Gulp**

1. Inside `set-env` instead of setting using `gulp-env`, I simply set a global variable `NODE_ENV='dev'`
2. Inside `webpack` task, I'm doing `webpackConfig['resolve']['alias']['config'] = webpackConfig['resolve']['alias']['config'].replace(/<envt>/, NODE_ENV);`

This worked for me